# Did not enable "Download updates" and "Install-third party software" during installation. How do I turn then on?

Tags: system-installation

I did not enable "Download updates" and "Install-third party software" during installation. I am wondering how to turn them on. I am a new user and nothing is very familiar to me right now.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 2):

From Ubuntu Software go to: Software Updates and in the Ubuntu Software and Updates tabs enable the ones you want enabled. This works for 16.04 but the behavior should be pretty similar unless you have a really old version.
[image]

[image]